# Mac app to show hard drive consumption/usage?

Tags: software-recommendation, disk-space

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I find more disk space?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/860/how-can-i-find-more-disk-space)

Is there a program or app that i can use to tell me where all of my hard disk space has gone? I'd like a graph (pie chart) if possible, but I prefer free/low cost over the aesthetics of such a program.

Comment: If you're comfortable with the command line/terminal, `du -hs *` will get you far.  Even better, the same command will work on just about any *nix system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[DaisyDisk](http://www.daisydiskapp.com/) should suit your needs. It costs $19, but has a free trial available. Paying for the app gives you:

- No "nag-screens", badges or overlays
- All functions, including the in-app deletion, are available
- Free updates
- Priority support by e-mail
- One license can be used on multiple Macs

So registering isn't exactly *required* and there isn't a time limit, but there are some features that you don't get with the free version.

Comment: This did the trick for me! I may register eventually.

Comment: I've tried a number and settled on DaisyDisk. Fast and well designed with a UI that "just works".

Answer (score 5):

[Disk Inventory X](http://www.derlien.com/) is a great tool for this. While its not a pie chart, it is a visual graph of your usage, as well as relative sizes to other files. Colors are also used to group like files together. I have used this a few times to find what was using up extra disk space.

Its free too.

Comment: Saved again several GB thanks to it this week. Don't just run it once but do it from time to time. Also, I had to use the beta version on my SnowLeopard MBP. The one proposed by default just crashes at launch.

Comment: Yah, pretty sure it hasn't been updated in a while except that beta to run on newer machines.

Answer (score 1):

I've been using [GrandPerspective](http://grandperspectiv.sourceforge.net/) for several years now and been very happy.

Answer (score 0):

[WhatSize](http://www.whatsizemac.com/) is my tool of choice and has a free trial. If I didn't need the extra functionality it allows, I would also check out a free trial of [DaisyDisk](http://www.daisydiskapp.com/). Although it's more focused on pretty animations and presentation than full function (at this point in it's life), there are advantages to getting [DaisyDisk through the Mac App Store](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/daisydisk/id411643860?mt=12). [GrandPerspective](http://grandperspectiv.sourceforge.net/) makes my head hurt but I know many people who swear by it instead of at it.