# Delete junk files in Os X 10.8.4

Tags: file, macos

On my computer i have got 30GB of junk files. I looked for it everywhere. In both Librarires and other folders. So, is there some method to identify those files and delete them? Some kind of script or app. 
Thanks!

Comment: How do you know it's junk?

Comment: The script is easy (and very dangerous)- _for file in \`cat /path/to/junk.txt\`; do rm $file; done_ but it should probably test that you have a good backup that you can restore if it deletes files that are needed rarely (like at boot time) and not really junk.

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of apps which will show you how your disk space is being used. My preference is [OmniDiskSweeper](http://www.omnigroup.com/products/omnidisksweeper/download/) which is free. Launch it and have it search your $HOME folder (⌘ + Shift + H) and it will sort the directories according to disk usage.

Answer (score 1):

You can also enable calculating all sizes from the view options in Finder:

[image]

You can show hidden files by running `defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles -bool true; killall Finder`.

Part of the disk space could be taken up by `/var/vm/sleepimage` if you have a laptop, or by `/Volumes/MobileBackups` if you use Time Machine.

Related questions:

- [Reducing Lion OS Footprint by removing unnecessary files/folders](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/48919)
- [How can I figure out what's slowly eating my HD space?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/5353/how-can-i-figure-out-whats-slowly-eating-my-hd-space)

Answer (score 0):

[CleanMyMac 2](http://macpaw.com/cleanmymac) works for me too.
Amazingly simple. Highly recommended.

Comment: This app has already been mentioned.

Answer (score -2):

Try "[CleanMyMac 2](http://macpaw.com/cleanmymac)" its quite good app , removes lot of junk files and improves the performance considerably.

Comment: Could you add some details? Link to the app, what it does, etc.

Comment: By what measure is performance improved? I've found most apps like this take the user 30 minutes to find and install and usually they end up costing time down the road when deleted files are needed later (or cause errors in update packages when files with receipts showing them installed are now gone). I can't say this CleanMyMac 2 app is snake oil, but some details might let others know its not. As a category, the value of a "magic tool" is often over-hyped and the downsides of them get downplayed by vendors and their advocates.